# Can I use Teachable Machine on Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

I found out that tensorflow lite was available in Raspberry Pi Pico.

So is the teachable machine available in Raspberry Pi Pico?

I don't know because I don't have any knowledge of this. What should I do if possible?

Comment: I think so. Please see this [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/teachable-machine-raspberry-pi-tensorflow-camera)

Comment: @JaesungChung
Unfortunately, That used Raspberry Pi 4.
Pico has poor performance compared to 4.
Pico can do that??

Comment: I see. Raspberry Pi Pico is a microcontroller form factor. Please check out TFLite micro project for getting more information, https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers There are a few limitations for microcontroller environment.